# What is Radagast the Brown's fate?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I recently read a poem by Tolkien that said Gandalf was the only Istari to return to Valinor,which made me wonder if Radagast had been banished like Saruman had.